# How to count the values which are repeating in an array using RDD,dataframe,dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd, apache-spark-dataset

I have to count the repeating values in an array

```
val arr = Array(1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5)
```

For example how to count the number of 5s in the array using RDD, Dataframe, Datasets?

Answer (score 1):

If you put your Scala array int into Seq

```
val arr = Seq(1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5).toDF("num")
val counts = arr.groupBy($"num").agg(count($"num"))
scala> counts.show
+---+----------+
|num|count(num)|
+---+----------+
|  1|         1|
|  3|         1|
|  5|         3|
|  4|         1|
|  2|         2|
+---+----------+
```

Comment: ok..ty..for example if I want only one number count like for example 5 then?

Comment: arr.filter("num==5").groupBy($"num").agg(count($"num"))

Comment: I wouldn't use groupBy because of the shuffle penalty. I'd use a simple foreachPartition along with Accumulator.

Comment: @NirHedvat, that might depend on how many distinct values are expected. If a really large number, best to keep the results as a DF/RDD?